# Interpret Model error result.

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, error, measurement-error

I have a regression model and used some independent variables to estimate dependent variables.Now I am trying to evaluate the model performance by using percentage bias (p_bias) and Model efficiency (ME). Now I am confused here: In my result percentage bias is 146 while I am getting ME of 4.3. Is is reasonable to have such a value. How to interpret this result?

formula for ME and P_bias is taken from: https://www.geosci-model-dev.net/8/2187/2015/

Any help would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in the paper:

```
ME of 4.3. Is is reasonable
```

This is not! You actually refer to the r squared measure of model quality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

It can be negative, but it cannot be more than one.

> In my result percentage bias is 146

This can be, even if one of your model's prediction is severely less than real value (according to the formula in the paper), and I mean:

> Pbias gives an indication on whether the model results are
>   consistently under- or overestimated compared to the observations

is not necessarily about consistency.

Comment: Thank you @Alexey, for your quick response. So can I say that model perform good instead of having p_bias 146%?

Comment: Could you once again look at your calculation of ME, so that when you take 1 - (squared residuals / squared mean residuals), you make sure the right part cannot be negative?

Comment: **having p_bias 146%** is an indicator your model performans quite overestimates the real values, if you got it in a correct way, of course.